# Convert a common date format in an ISO week date format

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe, iso

i have this dataframe with this kind of date format

```
           Date  Week Number   Influenza[it]  Febbre[it]  Rinorrea[it]  
0    2008-01-01             1            220         585           103   
1    2008-01-08             2            403         915           147   
2    2008-01-15             3            366         895           136   
3    2008-01-22             4            305         825           136   
4    2008-01-29             5            311         837           121 
... ...
```

I'd like to convert the date format in the ISO week date format like this dataframe (because i need to intersect the two dataframes with the same dates, based on the years and weeks). The format is like "year-weeknumberoftheyear".

```
0     2007-42
1     2007-43
2     2007-44
3     2007-45
4     2007-46
... ...
```

So i was able just to find the ISO weeks of the first dataframe in this way:

```
wiki = pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
for i,d in wiki.iterrows():
    print d.Date.isocalendar()[1]
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
...
```

But i don't know how to make a date format like the second dataframe (in the way "year-weeknumberoftheyear")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a vectorized approach instead after the read operation:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%V')
df['Date']
0    2008-01
1    2008-02
2    2008-03
3    2008-04
4    2008-05
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Here, `%V` is the directive corresponding to ISO 8601 week number.

---

***demo:***

```
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
'''
Date     Week Number   Influenza[it]  Febbre[it]  Rinorrea[it]  
2008-01-01             1            220         585           103   
2008-01-08             2            403         915           147   
2008-01-15             3            366         895           136   
2008-01-22             4            305         825           136   
2008-01-29             5            311         837           121
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=['Date'], engine='python')
df
```

[image]

```
df['Date'].dtypes
dtype('<M8[ns]')

df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%V')
0    2008-01
1    2008-02
2    2008-03
3    2008-04
4    2008-05
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

---

***edit:*** (though inefficient, only for reproducibility purposes)

```
L = ['{}-{}'.format(d.Date.isocalendar()[0], str(d.Date.isocalendar()[1]).zfill(2)) for i,d in wiki.iterrows()]
```

Construct `series`:

```
>>> pd.Series(L)
0    2008-01
1    2008-02
2    2008-03
3    2008-04
4    2008-05
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi, i tried but nothing changes, the output is like this: 
0      2008-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: Alright! What's the dtype of `wiki['Date']`? Are those of `datetime64[ns]` type?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: No, you need to check `wiki['Date'].dtypes`

Comment: Sorry, yes it's  datetime64[ns]

Comment: So, you sure `wiki['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%V')` doesn't work as intended?

Comment: Wait, I'll make a mock `DF` and see if that works when you do. Btw, could you edit your post containing this output you've got?

Comment: Thanks but i don't understand, the problem is the dtype (not '<M8[ns]')?

Comment: I suppose you  need to do `wiki['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(wiki['Date'])` just before this. Might be those are in `pd.tslib.Timestamp` format. See my edit.

Comment: After that, when i run dtypes i have again: datetime64[ns]

Comment: It works in this way! I'm just now figuring out how to insersect those dates...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer is incorrect because **2022-01-01** would be converted to **2022-01**
and **the correct ISO week for this date is 2021-52** because by ISO definition it's still included in the last week of the previous year. You can see this here:

The best way I found to have a real ISO week so far is this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-12-31', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-04']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# df['wrong year-week'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%V') ## wrong ISO!

df['monday'] = df['date'] - pd.to_timedelta(arg=df['date'].dt.weekday, unit='D')
df['year-week'] = df['monday'].dt.strftime('%Y-%V')

## or in one-line:
df['year-week'] = (df['date'] - pd.to_timedelta(arg=df['date'].dt.weekday, unit='D')).dt.strftime('%Y-%V')
```

| date | year-week |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-31 | 2021-52 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2021-52 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2022-01 |

Answer (score 0):

time.strftime('%Y-%W') may work for you. It is used for format the time.

import pandas as pd
pd.to_datatime(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%W')
'1970-00' will be seen in the ouput

Comment: '%W':Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number [00,53]. All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0.